# PHP - Is It Possible To Insert Into Database The Session Name?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, session, session-variables

So I'm making a posting system with PHP.
When the user wants to create a post, all the fields need to be complete, and what I'm trying to do is to insert into the database the name of the session, for example, to insert to the database 'Edward', because that would be the name of the session.
Here's what I'm trying to do:

```
<?php

session_set_cookie_params(86400*30, "/");
session_start();

require 'admin/config.php';
require 'functions.php';

if (isset($_SESSION['user'])) {
    require 'view/new.view.php';
} else {
    header('Location: index.php');
}

$connection = connect($bd_config);
if (!$connection) {
    header('Location: error.php');
}

$errors = '';

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
    $title = cleanData($_POST['title']);
    $demo = cleanData($_POST['demo']);
    @$project_type = $_POST['project_type'];
    $content = $_POST['content'];
    $post_by = $_SESSION['user'];

    $errors = '';

    if (empty($title) or empty($demo) or empty($project_type) or empty($content)) {
        $errors .= '<p>Complete all the fields!</p>';
    } else {
        $statement = $connection->prepare("
            INSERT INTO posts (ID, title, demo, content, post_type)
            VALUES (null, :title, :demo, :content, :project_type)
        ");

        $statement->execute(array(
            ':title' => $title,
            ':demo' => $demo,
            ':project_type' => $project_type,
            ':content' => $content,
        ));

        $statement2 = $connection->prepare("
            INSERT INTO posts (post_by)
            VALUES ($post_by)
        ");

        $statement2->execute(array(
            $post_by
        ));

        header('Location: main.php');
    }   
}
?>
```

As you can see, I'm doing 2 `statement` variables for 2 SQL consults, but when I do that, it throws this error:

```
<b>Fatal error</b>:  Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'cesar' in 'field list' in C:\xampp\htdocs\bider\test2\new.php:52
Stack trace:
#0 C:\xampp\htdocs\bider\test2\new.php(52): PDOStatement-&gt;execute(Array)
#1 {main}
  thrown in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\bider\test2\new.php</b> on line <b>52</b><br />
```

It marks 'cesar' cause that's the session name, I guess.
Can someone help?

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-id.php

Comment: Yes you can though why?

Comment: You can, but what purpose would it serve?

Comment: This will be for when the user creates a new post, its username is saved to the posts database, so when displaying the post, it says by  who was uploaded :)

Comment: Ah ok. When you said "Session name" we thought you meant the internal session ID used by PHP to uniquely identify each session object in memory. Storing that wouldn't make sense.

Comment: Anyway the second query is the problem - you're not using parameters properly. Compare it to your first one and spot the difference

Comment: Ok, but when I use ':' at the beginning, lets say
    ':post_by' => $post_by
It marks this: Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'cesar' in 'field list' in C:\xampp\htdocs\bider\test2\new.php:50 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\bider\test2\new.php(50): PDOStatement->execute(Array) #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\bider\test2\new.php on line 50

Comment: Are you sure? because you definitely didn't put "cesar" as any of the column names in any of those queries here. Which line is line 50, exactly? Your code for the second query should be `$statement2 = $connection->prepare("
            INSERT INTO posts (post_by)
            VALUES (:post_by)
        ");

        $statement2->execute(array(
            ":post_by" => $post_by
        ));`

Comment: Yes! That worked. Thank you soooo much for your support!

Comment: Ok. No idea what you were doing before to get that error but glad that works now. I will add it as a proper answer shortly so you can mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 1):

Your second query is the problem - you're not using parameters properly. Compare it to your first one and spot the difference in the structure. You need to specify a placeholder `:post_by` in the INSERT statement so PDO knows where to bind the variable, and you need to give the `$post_by` entry in the parameter array the same name as an index, so they match up.

Here's a version which will work:

```
$statement2 = $connection->prepare(
  "INSERT INTO posts (post_by) 
   VALUES (:post_by)"
);

$statement2->execute(array(
  ":post_by" => $post_by)
);
```